# HQL join without foreign keys on the table

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

Is it possible to do a join between 2 tables that don't have foreign keys?

**Edit:** Ok, I have been assured this is possible, but I'm not entirely sure how to do it yet.

**Classes**

```
public class Booking
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 bookingID { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 bookingAdminID { get; set; 
}

public class BookingLocation
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 bookingID { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 locationID { get; set; } 
}
```

**Mappings**

```
 public BookingMap()
 {
    Table("Bookings");

    Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID");
    Map(x => x.bookingID).Column("BookingID");
    Map(x => x.bookingAdminID).Column("BookingAdminID");
 }

public class BookingLocation
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 bookingID { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 locationID { get; set; } 
 }
```

I need to do a simple inner join on bookingID of both table above. How would I do that?

I have tried:

```
var hql = "select b from Booking as b inner join BookingLocation as bl on b.bookingID =   bl.bookingID";
var bookings = session.CreateQuery(hql).List<object[]>();
```

but I get the error:

> Semantic exception was unhandled by user code Path expected for join!
>
> [select b from Booking as b inner join BookingLocation as bl on
> b.bookingID = bl.bookingID]

**I am taking this approach because I can't easily build a relationship between these 2 tables in the mapping. Do you need to have a relationship in order to do a join?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding relationships to my entities like so:

```
 public class Booking
 {
     public virtual int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual Int32 bookingID { get; set; }
     public virtual Int32 bookingAdminID { get; set; }


     public virtual IList<BookingLocation> BookingLocations { get; set; }

     public Booking()
     {
         BookingLocations = new List<BookingLocation>();
     }
 }

public class BookingLocation
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 bookingID { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 locationID { get; set; } 
    public virtual Booking Booking { get; set; }
}
```

Even though they don't have foreign keys, I was then able to do a join like this:

```
var bookings = session.CreateCriteria<Booking>("p")
                              .CreateCriteria("p.BookingLocations", JoinType.InnerJoin)
                              .SetMaxResults(30) 
                              .List<Booking>();
```

Answer (score 4):

by 2 tables you mean two classes that are mapped to 2 tables correct? In that case you can just use the class (say two classes Foo & Bar that are mapped to some tables) as follows:

```
session.CreateQuery("select * from A as a, B as b 
where a.Prop1=:value1 and b.Prop2=:value2" //conditions if any)
.SetString("value1",val1)
.SetString("value2",val2)
.List<object[]>();
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have tried to use your advice, but I haven't been able to figure out the syntax. I have edited my original post, do you mind rewriting your sample code please?